# 405 (Method Not Allowed) in Angular JS With WCF Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, linq, wcf

Currently I am working on WCF project. I am consuming my wcf project into Angular JS Application but when I run the application it does not provide any error. There are errors when I launch developer tools in Google Chrome and I cannot insert, update and delete etc. It's showing following errors...... Anyone help me to correct this errors I would be grateful.

```
?o=3&g=EC0825C4-90A4-2692-D257-CD2C2B565912&s=1A2C77E8-0498-4A11-B8B8-D740DBEC71C4&z=1403834305:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
2angular.js:12701 OPTIONS http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Index:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
Modules.js:52 Some error Occured[object Object]
Index:1 GET http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent/ 400 (Bad Request)
angular.js:14642 ReferenceError: $log is not defined
    at Modules.js:18
    at angular.js:17000
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18182)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18480)
    at l (angular.js:12501)
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onload (angular.js:12655) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

Her is code in Angular JS ...

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
var app;

(function () {
    app = angular.module("RESTClientModule", []);

    app.controller("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController", function ($scope, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;
        //1 Mean New Entry  

        GetAllRecords();
        //To Get All Records  
        function GetAllRecords() {
            var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllStudent();
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Students = pl.data },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                });
        }

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.StudentID = "";
            $scope.Name = "";
            $scope.Email = "";
            $scope.Class = "";
            $scope.EnrollYear = "";
            $scope.City = "";
            $scope.Country = "";
        }

        //To Create new record and Edit an existing Record.  
        $scope.save = function () {
            var Student = {
                Name: $scope.Name,
                Email: $scope.Email,
                Class: $scope.Class,
                EnrollYear: $scope.EnrollYear,
                City: $scope.City,
                Country: $scope.Country
            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
                var promisePost = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.post(Student);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.StudentID = pl.data.StudentID;
                    GetAllRecords();

                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            } else {
                //Edit the record      
                debugger;
                Student.StudentID = $scope.StudentID;
                var promisePut = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.put($scope.StudentID, Student);
                promisePut.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.Message = "Student Updated Successfuly";
                    GetAllRecords();
                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
                });
            }
        };

        //To Get Student Detail on the Base of Student ID  
        $scope.get = function (Student) {
            var promiseGetSingle = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.get(Student.StudentID);
            promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
                var res = pl.data;
                $scope.StudentID = res.StudentID;
                $scope.Name = res.Name;
                $scope.Email = res.Email;
                $scope.Class = res.Class;
                $scope.EnrollYear = res.EnrollYear;
                $scope.City = res.City;
                $scope.Country = res.Country;
                $scope.OperType = 0;
            },
                function (errorPl) {
                    console.log('Some Error in Getting Details', errorPl);
                });
        }

        //To Delete Record  
        $scope.delete = function (Student) {
            var promiseDelete = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.delete(Student.StudentID);
            promiseDelete.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.Message = "Student Deleted Successfuly";
                GetAllRecords();
                ClearModels();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
            });
        }
    });

    app.service("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService", function ($http) {
        //Create new record  
        this.post = function (Student) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent",
                data: Student
            });
            return request;
        }

        //Update the Record  
        this.put = function (StudentID, Student) {
            debugger;
            var request = $http({
                method: "put",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/UpdateStudent",
                data: Student
            });
            return request;
        }

        this.getAllStudent = function () {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent");
        };

        //Get Single Records  
        this.get = function (StudentID) {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetStudentDetails/" + StudentID);
        }

        //Delete the Record  
        this.delete = function (StudentID) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "delete",
                url: "http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/DeleteStudent/" + StudentID
            });
            return request;
        }

    });

})();
```

Here is the WCF service Code ......

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IStudentService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/GetAllStudent/")]
        List<StudentDataContract> GetAllStudent();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/GetStudentDetails/{StudentId}")]
        StudentDataContract GetStudentDetails(string StudentId);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             UriTemplate = "/AddNewStudent")]
        bool AddNewStudent(StudentDataContract student);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/UpdateStudent")]
        void UpdateStudent(StudentDataContract contact);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "DeleteStudent/{StudentId}")]
        void DeleteStudent(string StudentId);
    }
}
```

Here is Implementation of method of wcf service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCF_REST_Service
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "StudentService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select StudentService.svc or StudentService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        StudentManagementEntities ctx;

        public StudentService()
        {
            ctx = new StudentManagementEntities();
        }

        public List<StudentDataContract> GetAllStudent()
        {
            var query = (from a in ctx.Students
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<StudentDataContract> studentList = new List<StudentDataContract>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
            {
                studentList.Add(new StudentDataContract
                {
                    StudentID = Convert.ToString(rec.StudentID),
                    Name = rec.Name,
                    Email = rec.Email,
                    EnrollYear = rec.EnrollYear,
                    Class = rec.Class,
                    City = rec.City,
                    Country = rec.Country
                });
            });
            return studentList;
        }

        public StudentDataContract GetStudentDetails(string StudentId)
        {
            StudentDataContract student = new StudentDataContract();

            try
            {
                int Emp_ID = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
                var query = (from a in ctx.Students
                             where a.StudentID.Equals(Emp_ID)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

                student.StudentID = Convert.ToString(query.StudentID);
                student.Name = query.Name;
                student.Email = query.Email;
                student.EnrollYear = query.EnrollYear;
                student.Class = query.Class;
                student.City = query.City;
                student.Country = query.Country;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
            return student;
        }

        public bool AddNewStudent(StudentDataContract student)
        {
            try
            {
                Student std = ctx.Students.Create();
                std.Name = student.Name;
                std.Email = student.Email;
                std.Class = student.Class;
                std.EnrollYear = student.EnrollYear;
                std.City = student.City;
                std.Country = student.Country;

                ctx.Students.Add(std);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(StudentDataContract student)
        {
            try
            {
                int Stud_Id = Convert.ToInt32(student.StudentID);
                Student std = ctx.Students.Where(rec => rec.StudentID == Stud_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                std.Name = student.Name;
                std.Email = student.Email;
                std.Class = student.Class;
                std.EnrollYear = student.EnrollYear;
                std.City = student.City;
                std.Country = student.Country;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteStudent(string StudentId)
        {
            try
            {
                int Stud_Id = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
                Student std = ctx.Students.Where(rec => rec.StudentID == Stud_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                ctx.Students.Remove(std);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is HTML CODE ...

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">
<head title="ASAS">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="stud in Students">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.StudentID}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Name}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Email}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Class}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.EnrollYear}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.City}}</span></td>
                            <td><span>{{stud.Country}}</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="get(stud)" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" data-ng-click="delete(stud)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student ID</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="StudentID" readonly="readonly" data-ng-model="StudentID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Student Name</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sName" required data-ng-model="Name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Email</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEmail" required data-ng-model="Email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Class</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sClass" required data-ng-model="Class" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Enrollement Year</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sEnrollYear" required data-ng-model="EnrollYear" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>City</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCity" required data-ng-model="City" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Country</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="sCountry" required data-ng-model="Country" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" data-ng-click="save()" />
                            <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear" data-ng-click="clear()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is screen shot when I run the application..
[image: click here to see the result]

Comment: `Response for preflight` - CORS issue

Comment: Can you please explain little more

Comment: CORS means Cross Origin Resource Sharing - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Ok.thnaks what is changes required in my code ?

Comment: the web page is trying to access a resource that is not coming from the same domain that the web page comes from. The server for the remote resource needs to allow this to happen, using CORS headers. Something in the request is triggering a preflight "OPTIONS" request - your WCF code makes no mention of OPTIONS request, so that's where the 405 method not allowed error is coming from

Comment: Fix 1: determine why you are getting a pre-flight request and stop it. Fix 2: deal with the pre-flight correctly

Comment: My WCFR Service running on localhost under the pot number 50028 and I am trying to insert ,update and delete data from sql database by using AngularJS though WCF Service. I mentioned  same address(http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/AddNewStudent") in JavaScript in Module.JS File for PUT,POST AND GET Data@Jaromanda X

Comment: I didn't ask for what port number or any information that you just commented ... fact 1. the request is not same origin - fact 2. the request is triggering a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request - fact 3. your server doesn't have code to handle `OPTIONS` requests - fact 4. this is why you get method not allowed, because your server doesn't allow the OPTIONS method - the link I posted before https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has all the information you need to successfully allow CORS requests

Comment: Ok thanks currently i am on the link you provided . What should i change in my code ??

Comment: Fix 1: determine why you are getting a pre-flight request and stop it. or Fix 2: deal with the pre-flight correctly - also you may want to make sure you're producing the appropriate CORS headers in all request responses

Comment: I need more time to cheek the about all things but if you can correct the errors that will save my time

Comment: I can't see what's triggering the preflight, because I can't see your request headers, so I can't help with that. I can't help with sending the appropriate response headers, nor with handling an OPTIONS request method, because I'm not familiar enough with WCF service code to know where to put such things. I'm sorry, but all I can tell you is why you are getting the response you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use `*` in `[ServiceContract]`. like this:

```c#
[WebInvoke(Method = "*"
```

That way, you allow your method to receive `OPTIONS` requests.

Then you should add this to your `web.config`:

```xml
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Do not forgot to handle `OPTIONS` requests. Something like this will solve it:

```c#
public List<StudentDataContract> GetAllStudent()
        {
          if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            return null;            
          var query = (from a in ctx.Students
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<StudentDataContract> studentList = new List<StudentDataContract>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
            {
                studentList.Add(new StudentDataContract
                {
                    StudentID = Convert.ToString(rec.StudentID),
                    Name = rec.Name,
                    Email = rec.Email,
                    EnrollYear = rec.EnrollYear,
                    Class = rec.Class,
                    City = rec.City,
                    Country = rec.Country
                });
            });
            return studentList;
        }
```

That's it. Good luck.

Comment: Where i should add this if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") return;

Comment: in your each service. i updated my answer. hope you can figure it out.

Comment: You also mentioned  i have to use * sigh in webInvoke . Thats okk. What should i do with webGet ?? Shall i live it or any change with this as well . Thank

Comment: use web invoke instead of web get.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: David do i have to make any changes in module.JS Script ??

Comment: Sorry David Still same is showing ..when i run the application . It is now saying ...Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: when I click this link http://localhost:50028/StudentService.svc/GetAllStudent/  from Console window Its Takes  to wcf service page and says The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

Comment: you also mentioned I need to use * in servicecontract but I can not use it